# Max and Min in a month different per day when using Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, dynamic-sql

I got a strange issue.
I have two Stored Procedures, very similar.
one calculates the total KWh usage for the whole month,

```
SET     @SQL =
N'SELECT '''+ RIGHT(convert(varchar(11), DATEADD(m,0, @Date),106),8)+''' AS Reporting_Period,
    MAX(A) - MIN(A) AS KWh
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE [timestamp] BETWEEN '''+ @FirstDay +'''AND '''+ @EndThisMonth +''' '
```

and the other one calculates the same thing but per day, as below

```
SELECT CAST(timestamp as DATE) AS Day,
    MAX(A) - MIN(A) AS KWh
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE [timestamp] BETWEEN '''+ @FirstDay +'''AND '''+ @EndThisMonth +''' 
    GROUP BY CAST(timestamp as DATE) 

     '
```

but when I sum the Kwh column per day together, the value is slightly different from the first query.

for both queries variables are identical

```
DECLARE 
        @SQL            NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @EndThisMonth   NVARCHAR(20),
        @FirstDay       NVARCHAR(20)
SET     @EndThisMonth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH (@Date)),126)

SET     @FirstDay     = CONVERT(varchar(20),DATEADD(DAY,1, EOMONTH (@Date,-1)),126)
```

Any Idea?
Note: I simplified the query but it has to be Dynamic SQL and it is only one column A

here is the Sample Data:

```
timestamp                     A
----------                 -------
2017-10-19 01:00:00          135.5
2017-10-19 02:00:00          146.5
2017-10-19 03:00:00          157.2
2017-10-19 04:00:00          169.1
2017-10-19 05:00:00          176.8
 .....
 .....
 .....
2017-10-20 04:00:00          334.5
2017-10-20 05:00:00          349.7
2017-10-20 06:00:00          358.5
 .....
 .....
 .....
```

Comment: ...and your kWh is FLOAT?

Comment: Another question is about you LOGIC: why should the sum of (max-min) equal to max-min?

Comment: simple sample data to highlight the problem would help you get an answer

Comment: Just for clarification: which data type is your column timestamp? And what about your grouping of the first query?

Comment: Add the CREATE definition for MyTable

Comment: @Tyron78,
 please see the sample data, and i want to have two result set, one to give me the Total Kwh consumption per day, one give me Total Kwh consumption of the month, since I am using them for two different reports

Comment: @sepupic it is only one column and there is no negative value and values are always incremental.

Comment: @sepupic  
**but when I sum the Kwh column per day together, the value is slightly different from first**
I meant the result I get per day, when I add them together in excel is different from the result i get from first query  :)

Comment: Yesterday you had max(a) - min(b), that's why I answerd you what I saw. Ok, now it's more clear, but I repet my question: what is the data type of column A? Is it FLOAT?

Comment: @sepupic, It is real. I put a sample data in the question.   Another important thing is column A value are incremental all the times.

Answer (score 0):

I found where was my issue.

If you look at this table:

```
    timestamp                     A
    ----------                 -------
    2017-10-19 01:00:00          135.5
    2017-10-19 02:00:00          146.5
    2017-10-19 03:00:00          157.2
    .....
    .....
    2017-10-20 04:00:00          199.1
    2017-10-20 05:00:00          216
```

My first query for the whole month gets `max(A) - min(A)` of that month, which is
216 - 135.5 = 80.5 which is correct.

But when I do group them per day, I get the `Max(A)-Min(A)` of each specific day, which delta of each day should select as Max(A) of day 2 - Max (A) day 1.

See below

```
for Day 19/10
157.2-135.5=21.7

for day 20/10
216.8-199.1=17.7

Now the total is 
21.7+17.7=39.4  which is wrong.
```

then to calculate the total usage per day, I need to get max of day - max of previous day and then group them and below i achieved it by using cte

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, timestamp), 0) ) AS ROW,
      DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, timestamp), 0) AS DateVal,
      MAX(A) AS max_eTotal
  FROM 
      myTable
  GROUP BY
      DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, timestamp), 0)
)
SELECT c2.DateVal, c2.max_eTotal - c1.max_eTotal
FROM cte c1 
INNER JOIN cte c2 ON c1.row = c2.row-1
WHERE c2.DateVal BETWEEN @FirstDay AND @EndThisMonth
```

But thanks to everyone for the help